# Magento. Rewrite save for admin custom field

Tags: magento, field, admin

I created new field and included it into system.xml (Pin_Init_Block_Adminhtml_System_Robots)
Show i controled by _getElementHtml or render. 
How i can catch save?

```
   <?php
    class Pin_Init_Block_Adminhtml_System_Robots extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
    { 
        protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
        {
            //self::__writeRobots($element->getEscapedValue());

            $html = '<textarea id="'.$element->getHtmlId().'" name="'.$element->getName()
                 .'" '.$element->serialize($element->getHtmlAttributes()).'>'.self::__readRobots().'</textarea>'."\n";
            $html.= $element->getAfterElementHtml();
            return $html;
        }

        protected function __readRobots( )
        {
            $file = fopen( Mage::getBaseDir().'/robots.txt', "r");
            if(!$file) return $this->content;

            $content = '';

            while (!feof($file)):
                $content .= fgets($file);
            endwhile;

            fclose($file);
            return $content;
        }

        protected function __writeRobots( $content )
        {
            $file = @fopen( Mage::getBaseDir().'/robots.txt', 'w');
            @fwrite($file, "$content");
        }

        protected function _beforeSave()
        {
            self::__writeRobots('text1');
        }

        protected function _afterSave ()
        {
            self::__writeRobots('text1');
        }
    }
?>
```

File: /app/code/community/Pin/Init/Block/Adminhtml/System
XML:

```
<robots translate="label">
                            <label>Robots.txt</label>
                            <comment></comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>init/adminhtml_system_robots</frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </robots>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify to your element a `backend_model` then implement in that model the methods `_afterSave` and `_beforeSave`.
You can use as an example the `web/unsecure/base_url` element. It is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml` and has the backend model `adminhtml/system_config_backend_baseurl`.
That is equivalent to the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Baseurl`.
See what happens in there.
**UPDATE**
Make your config look like this:

```
<robots translate="label">
    <label>Robots.txt</label>
    <comment></comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>init/adminhtml_system_robots</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>init/adminhtml_system_backend_robots</backend_model><!-- add this line -->
    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</robots>
```

Now create the following class (put it in the proper file):

```
<?php 
class Pin_Init_Block_Adminhtml_System_Backend_Robots extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    { 
        //this is called before the value is saved
        $value = $this->getValue();//this is how you can get the value
        //do your magic with $value
    }
    protected function _afterSave()
    { 
        //this is called after the value is saved
        $value = $this->getValue();//this is how you can get the value
        //do your magic with $value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added code in question. Functions _afterSave and _beforeSave don't work for me. Have you any ideas?

Comment: @Vladimir. I've edited the answer. See if this helps you more.

Comment: Thanks it works. But i use "Pin_Init_Model_Robots" and "<backend_model>init/robots</backend_model>"

Comment: @Vladimir. The model you use is not important. I just put a name there to show how it should work.